# API for vehicles: makes, associated models

Tags: data-request, transportation, public-transport

I'd like to create an application based on cars, but I can't find any api that gives me the makes with the associated models, year and specifications. Could you help me?

I've done a lot of research but I'm only finding solutions that are either paying or incomplete.

Comment: Could you please add an example of what the API should give (request, response)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried From the [NHTSA API](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/)?

### Description

I'm not sure about the specifications but the description of NHTSA API from [Public APIs](https://publicapis.io/nhtsa-vehicles-api) says it has

> The National Highway Traffic Safety Administration (NHTSA) provides a public API that allows anyone to retrieve information about vehicles, including their make, model, year, and other relevant data.

From the NHTSA API site:

> The NHTSA Product Information Catalog Vehicle Listing (vPIC) Application Programming Interface (API) provides different ways to gather information on Vehicles and their specifications. The vPIC Dataset is populated using the information submitted by the Motor Vehicle manufacturers through the 565 submittals. All the information on how a VIN is assigned by the manufacturer is captured in this catalog and used to decode a VIN and extract vehicle information.

So from your question that should tick make, model, year. Specs is a bit harder to define but it appears to have access to quite a few (I am no car expert so can't say it will have everything you need, see the "list of specs" link below):

### Example API Calls

- [Honda models](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeIdYear/makeId/474/modelyear/2015?format=json)
- [List of specs](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getvehiclevariablelist?format=json)
- [Battery Types](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getvehiclevariablevalueslist/battery%20type?format=json)

### Extra info

- It appears the last code change was [15th July](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/Home/Index/ReleaseNotes) this year so that seems promising for it being maintained and having up to date data
- It also looks like you can download the database